# How can I use Level blueprint variables in an actor blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want an actor to control level blueprint variables.

Actually I am making a turn-based board game, and there has to be function like this:

ActorOnClicked -> Move the actor -> End turn('turn' is a level blueprint variable)

How can I get/set level blueprint variables?

Answer (score 0):

Actors could be in any levels so you can't access a specific level from an actor blueprint.

Instead the Actor should dispatch an event "EndTurn" that the level should hook up a listener to when that actor is created.

You can do this with "event dispatchers" https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/EventDispatcher/